# Calculus - Trouble finding symmetrical environment.

Tags: calculus, limits

Hello I'm having trouble to find a symmetrical environment I'll write the question and explain what I did.

Data :
$$
g(x) = \frac{1}{x}
$$

$$
\lim_{x \to \frac{1}{3}} g(x) = 3
$$

We need to find for what x exist f(x)$\in$N(N=Neighbourhood)1(3) --> (3-1,3+1) --> (2,4)

Finding a,b

$$
\frac{1}{a}=2
$$
$$
\frac{1}{b}=4
$$
a,b solutions are

$$
a = \frac{1}{2}
$$
$$
b = \frac{1}{4}
$$

The question is finding a symmetrical enviroment for $$\frac{1}{3}$$

So that's what I did:

Calculate both sides for symmetrical interval:

$$|\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3}| = \frac{1}{6}$$
$$|\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{4}| = \frac{1}{12}$$

The problem is that the enviroment that I found:

$$\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{12} = \frac{1}{4}$$
$$\frac{1}{6}-\frac{1}{12} = \frac{1}{12}$$

The problem is that:
$$\frac{1}{12}$$ 
Isn't part of the original interval (a,b).

Any ideas? Thanks.

EDIT :

I'll add an example from the learning book so it will be more clear.

Example (From the learning book):

Same function g(x) (as written above)

$$
\lim_{x \to \frac{1}{2}} g(x) = 2
$$

We will find for what X's appiles $g(x)\in$N1(2) --> (2+1, 2-1) --> (3,1)

Finding the a,b interval :

$$
\frac{1}{a}=1
$$
$$
\frac{1}{b}=3
$$

a,b solutions are :

$$
a=1
$$
$$
b=\frac{1}{3}
$$

So, we can conduct that $g(x)\in$N1(2) appiles to all $X\in$($\frac{1}{3}$,1) <-- Interval

Now we're looking for symmetrical enviroment for x=$\frac{1}{2}$

So :

$$|\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{2}| = \frac{1}{6}$$
$$|1-\frac{1}{2}| = \frac{1}{2}$$

N$\frac{1}{6}(\frac{1}{2})$ --> ($\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{6}$,$\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{6}$) --> ($\frac{1}{3},\frac{2}{3}$) which is also an symmetrical enviroment for x=$\frac{1}{2}$ and as well partially to the interval ($\frac{1}{3},1$)

Since ($\frac{1}{3},\frac{2}{3}$)$\subset$($\frac{1}{3},1$)

However in my case ($\frac{1}{12},\frac{1}{4}$)$\not\subset$($\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{2}$).

Comment: Your question "for what x exist f(x) N1(3) --> (2,4)" is not at all clear. Could you reword and reformat that to make it clear?

Comment: Sorry, encountered some difficulties with LaTeX, is it clear now?

Comment: It's still not clear. Are you trying to find an open interval, centered on x=$\frac{1}{3}$, such that the image of that under the function g is contained in the open interval (2,4)? If so, your answer of $\frac{1}{12}$ seems to be correct. As far as I can see, your *answer* does not need to be in the interval (a,b), you just use the answer to determine which (a,b) you mean.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to find an open interval that x=$\frac{1}{3}$ is the center, now I want this interval to have an symmetrical enviroment around x=$\frac{1}{3}$, but of course this enviroment must contained in interval (a,b) since x$\in$(a,b) I may lack vocabulary of mathematics terms in English, so I added an example, is it clear now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of $\frac{1}{{12}}$ that you got is not an end of the interval, it is the distance of both ends of the interval from the center. The center for you is $\frac{1}{{3}}$, so the desired interval is ($\frac{1}{3} - \frac{1}{{12}}$, $\frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{{12}}$), namely ($\frac{1}{4}$, $\frac{5}{12}$).

Comment: All clear, Thank you!